# Post the links on our pages our application does not work on mobile devices

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, hyperlink, facebook-php-sdk

I wonder if anyone is experiencing these problems, we from October 30:

When a user clicks on any links to our app from inside the Facebook native Android app (but not all devices, only some, we think it may be a problem with the latest version of facebook native, we even have any reports of iPhone users, but the main problem people we communicate with Android), they get this error “Either this application has not configured its Mobile Web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application. Unable to redirect.” We had never set a Mobile Web URL previously, and everything had been fine since we launched the app over a year ago. We sent all mobile clicks to the same URL’s as desktop browsers and handled the mobile rendering server-side. We have not changed our application domain inside the App Settings or anything like that.

In the App Settings, can set a Mobile Web URL to our homepage (www.ciberweb.com/www/movil.php) and the link works (and the error message goes away) but that’s not the desired behavior at all – it would mean that all links end up at the same Mobile Web URL regardless of what the link was!

I insist that there are hundreds of messages we send our fans.

The problem we are experiencing since 31 October and takes place primarily in the native app for Android movile and almost everyone seems to be no problem in the Web version of Facebook

We have very clear as to play safely in error, as the hundreds of reports from our Fans Any thoughts affect mainly Android devices with native Facebook application, but could not say when that version devices and safely.

The error occurs when our Fans do click on one of the link to our application shares in any of our web pages such as in https://www.facebook.com/OfertasTrabajoGranada or https://www.facebook.com/OfertasEmpleoValencia and they see it on his canvases or walls, but the problem is widespread, even we have asked some of our fans to try on other pages that use link-sharing systems like and seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug with Facebook, and it is best to subscribe to this developer's bug report to stay updated on the latest updates.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124107044413049

Comment: If I subscribe to this and other similar bug as https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/286474381470406?browse=search_50a4aa174b99a8e08898426 or https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403608616377424?browse=search_50a4aa174b99a8e08898426 and sent those bug our experiences ... even published a few days ago that bug me invalidated in: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297163397068397?browse=search_50a4aa174b99a8e08898426 

Our case we are losing a share of 35% of visitors and frustrating is that we paid about € 20 in advertising to attract new facebook fan which in many cases lose...